# How to make Rufus-scheduler reflect file changes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rufus-scheduler

I'm using Rufus-scheduler gem in my ROR application to send emails in the background. My setup is like:

```
# config/initializers/rufus_scheduler.rb

scheduler = Rufus::Scheduler.new(lockfile: '.rufus-scheduler.lock')

scheduler.cron '0 2 * * fri' do
    UserMailer.send_some_emails
end
```

Any changes I make in the `.send_some_email` class method isn't reflected in the Rufus-scheduler task, how can I fix this? I don't want to restart the server every time I make a change!

Comment: If I were you, I wouldn't talk about "fixing this", it behaves as expected, there is nothing to fix.

Comment: @jmettraux perhaps, but not as required.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's assume UserMailer.send_some_emails is defined in whatever/user_mailer.rb

```
scheduler = Rufus::Scheduler.new(:lockfile => '.rufus-scheduler.lock')

scheduler.cron '0 2 * * fri' do
  load 'whatever/user_mailer.rb'
  UserMailer.send_some_emails
end
```